# explorer favorites behavior

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have started using the Favorites navigation in Windows 7 Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer).  I have two different machines where it behaves differently.

On my laptop if I click a favorite link, the right pane opens to that location and the highlight remains on the favorite.

On my desktop if I click a favorite link, the right pane opens to that location and the highlight skips down to where the link exists in the file tree on the left pane.

I really prefer the way my laptop works, but I can't find a setting that affects the behavior.  Does anyone know what makes the two different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Automatically expand' option must not be checked.

[image: auto expand]